# How to Whitebox instantiate an abstract class for the purpose of replacing a method with test logic where I can manipulate the arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock

Preamble (**please read**):

- Dealing with legacy code that **I can't refactor** without an act of congress (but I have the sources).
- This legacy code interacts with **a lot of abstract classes** (and their various Implementations)
- **Mocking is not enough** because I need to intercept the method arguments sent to the abstract methods and manipulate them inside my replacement (test) logic
- I know **I could just extend** those abstract classes on my test package and provide implementations for the methods I want to replace. However **the goal of this question** is to see if there's a way around it, because in the case of abstract classes that have a ton of abstract methods (think SocketChannel from NIO) this is a ton of useless boilerplate code that makes the unit test unreadable.
- I know that **the legacy code is poorly designed** and that this is not the way of writing clean well designed unit-tests; that's not in question. Just know that the Legacy code can't be changed easily.

**The question is**: How to accomplish this (using **PowerMock**) without getting an exception from PowerMock saying that this class can't be instantiated because it's abstract:

```
@PrepareForTest({SocketChannel.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestThatUsesSocketChannelChannel
{
    replace(method(SocketChannel.class, "read", ByteBuffer.class)).with((proxy, method, args) -> 
    {
        // Line below intercepts the argument and manipulates it 
        ((ByteBuffer) args[0]).clear();
    });
    // The line below throws an exception (because SocketChannel is abstract)
    SocketChannel socketChannel = Whitebox.newInstance(SocketChannel.class);
    // Once here, ideally I can continue my test
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the answer**: Because SocketChannel is an abstract class, in order to use Whitebox.newInstance, there needs to be a preliminary step with ConcreteClassGenerator. This creates a run time child of SocketChannel with empty method implementations. Notice that before that I replaced the method I care for. Conclusion: this allows me to instantiate (an on-the-fly) child of an abstract class without me having to extend it explicitly. See the code above, now made to work with such intermediary step:

```
@PrepareForTest({SocketChannel.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestThatUsesSocketChannelChannel
{
    replace(method(SocketChannel.class, "read", ByteBuffer.class)).with((proxy, method, args) -> 
    {
        // Line below intercepts the argument and manipulates it 
        ((ByteBuffer) args[0]).clear();
    });
    // THIS Fixes it: generate a an on-the-fly class that implements stub methods
    // for the ones that are abstract and then (and only then) pass that to Whitebox
    Class<?> concreteSocketChannelClass = new ConcreteClassGenerator().createConcreteSubClass(SocketChannel.class);
    SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) Whitebox.newInstance(concreteSocketChannelClass);
    // Once here, ideally I can continue my test
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply mock the abstract class by using plain Mockito:

```
AbstractClass theMock = mock(AbstractClass.class);
```

Then inject this mock of the abstract class via PowerMock.

Comment: Check the preamble. I need to intercept the arguments for the method and then manipulate them inside my replacement logic.